# create multiple tabs in a loop with scrollbard in tkinter

Tags: loops, tkinter, scrollbar

I want to create multiple tabs in a loop with scrollbars in tkinter. Somehow the scrollbar only works in the last tab with the following code:

```
for i in range(ParameterTabNumber):

        z=ParameterTabs[i]
        FrameParametersMain=Frame(MainNotebook, background="#FFFFFF", width=200, height=150)
        FrameParametersMain.pack()
        MainNotebook.add(FrameParametersMain, text=str(z))
        my_FrameParametersMain.append(FrameParametersMain)
        canvasParameters = Canvas(FrameParametersMain, highlightthickness=0,bg='#FFFFFFF')
        canvasParameters.pack(side=LEFT, fill=BOTH, expand=1)
        my_CanvasParameters.append(canvasParameters)  
        scrollbarParameters = Scrollbar(FrameParametersMain, orient=VERTICAL, command=canvasParameters.yview)
        scrollbarParameters.pack(side=RIGHT, fill=Y)      
        my_scrollbarParameters.append(scrollbarParameters)     
        FrameParameters = Frame(canvasParameters)
        my_TopTabs.append(FrameParameters)           
        canvasParametersWidgits = Canvas(FrameParameters, highlightthickness=0,bg='#FFFFFF',width=1700, height=1000)
        canvasParametersWidgits.pack()
        canvasParameters.create_window((0,0), window=FrameParameters, anchor="nw")
        canvasParameters.configure(yscrollcommand=scrollbarParameters.set)
        canvasParameters.bind('<Configure>',lambda e: canvasParameters.configure(scrollregion = canvasParameters.bbox("all")))
```

Can someone help me to get this working please?

Vielen Dank.

Answer (score 1):

It is because you have used same variable `canvasParameters` inside the lambda.  You should use `e.widget` instead:

```py
canvasParameters.bind('<Configure>',lambda e: e.widget.configure(scrollregion = e.widget.bbox("all")))
```